# How do I make my dd-wrt router obtain a WAN IPv6?

Tags: dd-wrt, ipv6

My ISP, [Andrew & Arnold, provides IPv6 natively](http://aa.net.uk/kb-broadband-ipv6-tech.html). I'm using dd-wrt in my router. How do I make it obtain the WAN IPv6 and distribute it to computers in my network?

Comment: I seem to recall back when I was using dd-wrt, the default build didn't have support.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, oh, in 2015? *sigh*

Comment: I think this is the information your looking for: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6 ... IPv6 is still not very common in most of the world, so most dd-wrt builds do not have it built in or enabled, you have to have a compatible router, some knowledge of the command line.

Comment: Alas yes. My old router died, and the one I replaced it with seemed good enough out of the box. Maybe openwrt?

Comment: You created [aaisp] and didn't even give it an excerpt.

Comment: First, you get rid of DD-WRT and replace it with OpenWrt, which does support IPv6 out of the box, and is what A&A themselves recommend.

Comment: OpenWRT doesn't work on any of my routers or any of the routers I had available when I was purchasing: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/asus/rt-ac87u Furthermore, it comes with no UI. I want something better than the crappy built-in firmware but I don't want to spend countless hours configuring it (I did that in the past many, many times, now I spend most of my time building software).